# What is going on in this x86 instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
cmp    %eax,0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)
```

I understand that the eax register is being compared to something, but I have no idea what eax is being compared to.

In other words, what does

```
x80498d4 (,%ebx,4)
```

mean?

Comment: I believe this would be `cmp [ebx*4 + 80498d4h], eax` in Intel syntax. IOW, it compares what's at the address in the brackets with what's in `eax`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It compares eax to the contents of address [0x80498d4 + (4 * ebx)]

Source: http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring12/CSCI-GA.1144-001/addressing_modes.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It takes the value of EBX, multiple by 4, add the constant 0x80498d4 to it. This value will be interpreted as a address, and the content of that value will be compared with the value of the register eax.
And finally the cmp instruction will set the EEFLAG register.